# pass and return multi-dimensional arrays from a function in C++

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a function that takes two matrices as parameters and return the sum of these two matrices.

The following is the code, which fails to pass the compiler. I think the implementation of function is wrong, how to correct it?

```
#include <iostream>

int **func(int **array1, int **array2, int n){
    a1 = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
     a1[i][j]=array1[i][j]+array2[i][j];
   }
   return a1;
  }

 int main( ){

 int m1[2][2];
 int m2[2][2];

  m1[0][0]=1; m1[0][1]=2; m1[1][0]=3; m1[1][1]=4;
  m2[0][0]=1; m2[0][1]=2; m2[1][0]=3; m2[1][1]=4;

 int **m3;
  m3 = func(m1,m2,2);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: When it fails to pass the compiler, then post the compiler's output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int** Create2DMatrix(int);
int** AddMatrix(int**&,int**&,int);

void DeleteMatrix(int**&);


 int main( )
 {
     int myDimension=4; // for example
     int i,j;

     int** myFirstMatrix=Create2DMatrix(myDimension);
     int** mySecondMatrix=Create2DMatrix(myDimension);


     // for example without function *


     for (i=0;i<myDimension;i++)
     {
         for (j=0;j<myDimension;j++)
         {
             // for example
             myFirstMatrix[i][j]=i+j;
             mySecondMatrix[i][j]=2*i+7*j-16;
         }
     }

     // show matrix 1
     for (i=0;i<myDimension;i++)
     {
         for (j=0;j<myDimension;j++)
         {
             cout<< myFirstMatrix[i][j] << " ";
         }
         cout << endl;
     }
     cout << endl;

     // show matrix 2
     for (i=0;i<myDimension;i++)
     {
         for (j=0;j<myDimension;j++)
         {
             cout<< mySecondMatrix[i][j] << " ";
         }
         cout << endl;
     }

     int** finalMatrix=AddMatrix(myFirstMatrix,mySecondMatrix,myDimension);

     // show sum of matrix
     cout << endl;
     for (i=0;i<myDimension;i++)
     {
         for (j=0;j<myDimension;j++)
         {
             cout<< finalMatrix[i][j] << " ";
         }
         cout << endl;
     }

     DeleteMatrix(myFirstMatrix);
     DeleteMatrix(mySecondMatrix);
     DeleteMatrix(finalMatrix);




    return 0;
 }

 int** Create2DMatrix(int dim)
 {
     int** myMatrix=new int*[dim];
     int* linearTable=new int[dim*dim];
     for (int i=0;i<dim;i++)
     {
         myMatrix[i]=linearTable+i*dim;
     }
     return myMatrix;
 }

 void DeleteMatrix(int**& MatrixToDel)
 {
     delete [] MatrixToDel[0];
     delete [] MatrixToDel;
     MatrixToDel=0;
 }

 int** AddMatrix(int**& MatrixOne,int**& MatrixTwo,int dimension)
 {
     int** sumMatrix=Create2DMatrix(dimension);
     for (int i=0;i<dimension;i++)
     {
         for (int j=0;j<dimension;j++)
         {
             // for example
             sumMatrix[i][j]=MatrixOne[i][j]+MatrixTwo[i][j];
         }
     }
     return sumMatrix;
 }
```

Comment: ofc you can reedit code to create Matrix(dim1,dim2) = > int** myMatrix=new int*[dim1] ... => int** Create2DMatrix(int dim1,int dim2) ... = > int* linearTable=new int[dim1*dim2] ... => myMatrix[i]=linearTable+i*dim2; :)))

Comment: @user672117, thanks. What you posted is exactly what I want to learn, i.e., how to pass array in a function. However, i do not understand how the DeleteMatrix works? what's the difference between " delete [] MatrixToDel[0];" and " delete [] MatrixToDel;"
   why do we need  MatrixToDel=0; ?

Comment: its not a difference, u must do it :) U have an array of numbers and adress of this array is at MatrixToDel[0].After Delete [] MatrixToDel[0] u need to free(?) an array of pointers <- MatrixToDel. MatrixToDel=0 <---- its for safety, u have to clean pointer MaatrixToDel because u sent it to function by refference;

Comment: And im not sure that AddMatrix(int**& MatrixOne,int**& MatrixTwo,int dimension) is used correctly here .... U Need to ask an expert :P Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int **func(int **array1, int **array2, int n) ;
```

To the above prototype, program cannot pass two dimensional arrays( i.e., [][]) because two dimensional array decays to a pointer to one dimensional array. So, the prototype should be -

```
int** func( int array1[][2], int array2[][2], int n );
```

---

**Edit:** With the above correction made , program needs to allocate memory for 2D array as @brado86 suggested. But, program also needs to deallocate the resources acquired by *new*, else memory leak prevails.

```
int main( ){

   // .......

   int **m3;
   m3 = func(m1,m2,2);      // m3 is pointing to the resources acquired in func(..)
                            // So, the resources acquired should be returned to
                            // free store. 

   for( int i=0; i<2; ++i )
       delete[] m3[i] ;

   delete[] m3 ;

   return 0;

}
```

Learn to use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/), that does this deallocation for process by default. And the two dimensional array can be represented as vector of vector of ints. (`i.e., vector<vector<int>> twoDimensionalArray;` )

Comment: just put the space between `>>` to be compatible with C++03

Comment: the implementation of int** func( int array1[][2], int array2[][2], int n ); assumes that the column is 2. But what if the column is not known beforehand and depends on n only? Then how to revise this function? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

as soon as this is C++, use `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` or `boost::array<boost::array<int, 2>, 2 >`. their usage is trivial and safer. and you still can learn from @Mahesh's answer how to do this with raw arrays.

Comment: I was writing my edit and in between got interrupted. +1 for good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

An `int[]` will decay to an `int*`, but an `int[][]` will NOT decay to an `int**`. Use a class which contains the array and take a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your function: you need to specify the type of a1

```
int **a1 = new int[n][n];
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
a1 = new int[n][n];
```

will not work.

Instead, allocating 2D C++ arrays goes like this:

```
int **a1;
a1 = new (int *)[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a1[i] = new int[n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a matrix with dynamic size like this. It's ok for your first two matrices because they are statically compiled, but the one you create in the function must be created dynamically that way:

```
int ** a1 = new int*[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) a1[i] = new int[n];
```